# CircleCI Github fails "No configuration was found in your project" with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, config, circleci

I'm trying to integrate CircleCI into Gthub in combination with my AndroidX project. I've added the config.ymlfile in Android Studio but Cricle CI keeps saying:

> No configuration was found in your project. Please refer to https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/ to get started with your configuration.

I have tead the documenation but whatever I do it does not find the config file. Could someone help me?

Screenshot from Github:
[screenshot-github-dir-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqpql.png)

Comment: Can you see the `config.yml` file in the `.circleci` folder on GitHub? You might need to commit changes before CircleCI sees it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I stoped the CircleCI built and committed the config file again. It is there but somehow it does not see it...

I'm maybe thinking that it is in the wrong structure... maybe I have to place te .circleci folder somewhere else?

Comment: I solved it indeed by rebuilding everything. Somehow circleci did not pick up the files.

Comment: Got into the same, I just had to re-run the build.